# Are there combined USB-C and Thunderbolt Docks with many ports available?

Tags: laptop, docking-stations

We use various Dell notebooks at the company and now I would like to buy a docking station for my home office.
Unfortunately some of the notebooks only have USB-C, while others have Thunderbolt.
Also some have a single port meant for a dock and some have two.

When I see this right, Dell has the WD19TB (single Thunderbolt) and WD19DC (dual USB-C).
The WD19TB has not enough charging power for the big Dell Precision notebooks.
On the other side, the WD19DC lacks Thunderbolt.

So basically I would need a merge of both and a bunch of USB 3.x downstream ports more.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no dock supports both Thunderbolt and USB-C for the upstream connection. It seems to me that a USB-C-based dock should be sufficient; would a USB-C dock with (optionally) another USB hub attached not suffice?

Comment: @JMY1000 I would prefer to have LAN and other things on PCI express (via Thunderbolt) for performance reasons. I also connect a lot of lab equipment on USB which takes bandwidth and it is sometimes tricky to properly distribute it across the root hubs to have sufficient performance there.
Second is that I would like to connect 1-2 4K2K screens (I am not sure about the final setup) so I can attend meetings and continue to work.

Comment: I think you’re probably just going to have to choose between Thunderbolt and USB. Bandwidth-wise I think 10Gb/s USB should be sufficient for everything you listed; your point about root hubs is well taken, but with the right dock, I think that should be a non-issue.

Comment: One World Computing has a forthcoming (mid-December) Thunderbolt Dock with a total of 4 Thunderbolt 4 / USB-C ports: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-dock. The Thunderbolt 4 host port provides up to 90W of power to the host computer.